# SQL Server 2008 Replicating Linked Server Tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, linked-server

I have a SQL2008 server with a linked Sybase server. I have several tables on the SQL2008 server that I need have merge replicated to some SQL2008 Express clients. I also need to get two tables from the linked Sybase server down to the SQL2008 Express clients. These two tables won't be updated at all on the SQL2008 Express clients, but are just used in a read only fashion to augment information in the other tables. Ideally I would also want to filter data from these two tables using a join filter based on one of the SQL tables that is replicating down.

Is there anyway for me to do this short of creating two corresponding tables in SQLServer 2008 and programatically inserting the rows I need replicated into these two new tables?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server replication can't use a Sybase table as the publisher.  You will need to look into the Sybase replication options.  Perhaps you can replicate the data from the Sybase server to the SQL 2008 server, then use SQL Server replication to replicate that data down to the SQL 2008 Express clients.

Comment: I don't really have the option to touch the Sybase Server

Comment: Last time I worked with Sybase, replication was a separate product

Comment: Without being able to make changes to the Sybase Server you'll need to build something which pulls the data from the Sybase server and loads updated/new data into a table in the main SQL Server, then use replication to push that data down to the Express instances.